# Is it possible to make continue loop on Server?

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, loops, servlets

My question is something different. But i've just a little confusion.

Suppose i've created a program in jsp like this(Please do not find out the mistakes from this program, It's just for understanding the confusion):

```
public run(){
    for(int i=0; i<=1000; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Counting: "+i);
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And i've created a button in `Html` to start this loop. Okay!

Suppose, I've a web hosting site called Openshift.. or anyone etc..

Now after deploying this Project into server. Is it possible when i press to start that loop, and after switching off my coumputer or Internet. It continuously counts loop until 1000 on Internet? Whether my computer gets switched off or removing internet cable?

Please let me know .. I've a still doubt because On Internet Apache server is still `on` whether our computer/laptop is `off`. Doesn't it?

***Surely, help would be appreciatede!!***

Comment: Two things. One is that when you close your session, the code execution stops actually. The second thing is, that you can programm a shell script and a cron task. When the script gets executed (exec) then it would set the cron task to start in like 1 second and then it can't be stopped. Just thinking

Comment: @jPO: So is it possible to make something like .. ? loop continuously counts whether my computer gets `switched off` and it still would work?

Comment: Sure! But indirectly as I mentioned. But when you execute the run code from your browser and the while loop is inside that file, it will be cancelled. You really have to do it at least as I mentioned. I am sure, there is a nicer way to do that, but that'd be my approach.

Comment: Questions about computer and how it works are offtopic on stackoverflow.

Comment: @RomanC I'm not asking about computer... I just want to know the process... Into my project. I've to make something like this... please help! :(

Comment: *Whether my computer gets switched off or removing internet cable?* Is this your problem?

Comment: As @jPo told that it would destroy the sessiob in between client... Any other solution??

Comment: you even know what means destroy the session??? read a begginer server manual first and ask later....

Answer (score -1):

If your server is hosted on your computer, of course not.
If on the other hand, you have your application hosted on a remote server, it will be able to run as long as that server is up and running, regardless whether your machine is online.

Comment: `Remote Server`? do you mean.. If i deployed my project on `Openshift hosting site`? right? Still it would work?

Comment: Server will run, but the session gets destroyed. I mean not the cookies but the session between him and server.

Comment: @jPO: So is it possible to make something like .. ? loop continuously counts whether my computer gets `switched off` and it still would work?

Comment: @jPO indeed, the session will be lost, but, if he implements a login-session and links the count to it. Or, generate a file on the server in which the count is written. Not an efficiënt way, but possible.